# Not able to update document of mongodb by java application

Tags: java, mongodb, eclipse

I have Written a java code to update document in mongodb database  my code is running msystem.out.println is getting print but the data is not getting updated

```java
public static void main(String []args) {
            
            
             MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient( Aws ip , port );
              //Connecting to the database
              MongoDatabase database = mongo.getDatabase("database");
              //Creating a collection object
              MongoCollection<Document>collection = database.getCollection("xyz");
            
              //Updating a document
              collection.updateOne(Filters.eq("_id", "60e53f4647c79a1db4821e4e"), Updates.set("comment", "IncorrectForm"));
              System.out.println("Document update successfully...");
         
           }
```

what can i do know ....

Comment: The way you have written the code,`System.out.println` will always run irrespective of whether the data in db gets updated or not.

Comment: Are you sure the `_id` field contains a string and not an ObjectId?

Comment: yehh  it contains object id how to deal with that

Comment: Have you tried running the update for that "_id" from mongoshell and checked for any results or errors? Also if you could capture the return values and print those it might provide some hint as to what is happening.